# How to install mysqldb on Openshift with flask

Tags: python, mysql, openshift

I am planning on making a website using Python + Flask + Mysql. My database requirements are very simple and hence I don't plan on using an ORM. Now I have been reading through the tuorials of mysqldb which is a C based mysql connector for Python. How can I install it on openshift?

For installing it on my local pc, I had to run the following two commands.

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Almost all of the results returned by Google show how to install Mysql cartridge instead of Mysqldb

Comment: Create a virtualenv for your website and use pip within the env to install any module that you need.

Comment: Darth Vader, that would work on local and on OpenShift but it is not the preferred mechanism. Requirements.txt is the right way

Answer (score 1):

Here is doc that shows how to spin up a Flask app on OpenShift

https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html

All you do is add the dependencies for the MySQL drivers into your requirements.txt as well and OpenShift will pull the deps and then put them in your app.